# The distribution of the average number of errors per article, depending on who typed it

Tags: probability

A typing agency employs 2 typists. The average number of errors per article is 3 when typed by the first typist and 4.2 when typed by the second. If your article is equally likely to be typed by either typist, approximate the probability that it will have no errors.

I know I can use a poisson distribution, but how do I interpret the equally likely part?  Is it as simple as I think it is?

Answer (score 0):

As a start, I would say $\Pr(N=0) = \Pr(N=0|T_1)\cdot \Pr(T_1) + \Pr(N=0|T_2)\cdot \Pr(T_2)$. Equally likely in this case would mean $\Pr(T_1) = \Pr(T_2) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Could I use Bayes Theorem?